# How can i fix the height of my image on mobile?

Tags: html, css

[image: on computer inspector width mobile with]

[image: screenshot of mobile]

Hello, i have problem with my image, the first image is on the inspector width mobile width, the second is a screen shot of the mobile.

As you can see, the height of the image is strange on the mobile screen shot and i don't know what's wrong with my code.

Tanks

```
<div class="text-image">
  <div id="text">
   <p>FEEL</p>
   <p>THE</p>
   <p>MOMENTS</p>
  </div>
   <img id="image" src='/images/test.png' alt='test'/>
  </div>


.text-image{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#image{
    width: 30%;
    height: auto !important;
}


#text{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: right;
    justify-content: center;
}

#text p{
    color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    font-size: 6vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the height to 100% instead of auto. if it looks weird still try changing it to 30% to match your width.

```
    #image{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It is actually working, nice to know the solution now!

Comment: Awesome! I'm curious, which one worked the 100% or the 30%?